# Best way to retrieve New York City addresses from SQL address field

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have a full address stored as a single string in my database table (MS SQL Server).

```
"1234 Fake Ave Astoria, NY 12345"
```

I have a bunch of records from different states but I need an easy way to retrieve records from New York State and New York City.

I thought about collecting NY State zipcodes and NYC zipcodes but I don't know where to find that info. But also not every address has a zip code.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: First of all, consider changing your database to have zip/state/address/address2 in different fields.  Next, what have you tried so far and found to not work?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**Geocoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) or for a Text Search

Comment: @ dfundako, Sadly the DB structure is designed by an ERP solution. No way of splitting up the field.

Comment: @ dfundako, I've tried collecting zip codes (which worked) but I noticed that some data were missing zips. So I'm left with working based on the city. There are a lot of neighborhoods for New York City, having trouble rounding that information up

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, I thought about Geocoding but some of the services I found are free up until a certain number of requests (like 2,500 lookups per day)

Comment: This is going to be a gnarly project.  Is this data entered in manually by a user?  Can the city be 'NYC'? Can things be misspelled?

Comment: You ask for the best way, and that is a Geocoding service. You can build a tool to help you determinate how probably will be a NY city, but even there you will need some manual process for validation

Comment: Haha, gnarly isn't the word I'm thinking. The data is entered manually by users. So cities can be annoying as "Long Island City, NY" or "LIC, NY" or "L.I.C, NY" and assuming states are "NY" and not "New York". It's looking more like a manual job

Answer (score 0):

If it's free text that has been entered over time, there is never going to be a perfect query to tackle this.
When I have these sort of data issues, I basically string together a series of WHERE clauses to pull out data I need, but you will still have to review and cleanse the data.

potentially, something along the lines of

```
WHERE address LIKE '%NY%' OR address LIKE '%New York%'
```

and build up from there.  As you said, if you can obtain a list of ZIP codes, then you could incorporate that too, but it's really down to the state of the data.

Comment: Just to expand, this is going to be a very manual process.  The code you provided will grab '123 Pony Street St Louis, MO' and '555 New York St Redlands, CA'

Comment: I noticed you can download ZIP codes pretty easily, from places such as:
http://www.zipcodestogo.com/New%20York/

You could try grabbing the RIGHT 5 characters from the address and seeing if they can match against a ZIP Code...again, purely down to the state of the data.

Comment: @Mikey, thanks for the link. I attempted that and found out that some of the address are missing zips. If there was somewhere that lists all cities for New York City, that would help with the remaining addresses. It's looking like I might have to manually collect this info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zip code in all the addresses, you may try grabbing all the post codes/zip codes of Newyork from any website &dumping them into a table and then do a query like

```
JOIN  POSTCODETable ON CHARINDEX(PostCode,address )>0 AND WHERE address LIKE '%NY%' OR address LIKE '%New York%'
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE Table_ZipCode (ZipCode  NVARCHAR(20))

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up from my previous comment you can make the zip code table using below query:

I got the zip codes from http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/ny/

```
CREATE TABLE Table_ZipCode (ZipCode  NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('00501')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('00544')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('06390')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10001')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10002')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10003')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10004')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10005')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10006')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10007')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10008')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10009')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10010')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10011')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10012')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10013')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10014')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10015')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10016')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10017')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10018')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10019')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10020')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10021')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10022')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10023')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10024')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10025')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10026')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10027')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10028')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10029')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10030')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10031')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10032')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10033')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10034')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10035')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10036')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10037')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10038')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10039')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10040')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10041')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10043')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10044')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10045')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10046')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10047')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10048')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10055')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10060')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10069')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10072')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10079')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10080')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10081')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10082')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10087')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10090')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10094')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10095')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10096')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10098')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10099')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10101')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10102')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10103')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10104')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10105')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10106')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10107')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10108')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10109')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10110')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10111')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10112')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10113')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10114')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10115')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10116')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10117')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10118')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10119')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10120')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10121')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10122')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10123')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10124')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10125')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10126')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10128')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10129')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10130')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10131')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10132')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10133')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10138')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10149')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10150')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10151')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10152')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10153')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10154')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10155')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10156')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10157')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10158')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10159')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10160')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10161')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10162')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10163')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10164')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10165')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10166')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10167')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10168')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10169')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10170')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10171')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10172')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10173')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10174')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10175')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10176')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10177')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10178')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10179')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10184')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10185')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10196')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10197')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10199')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10203')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10211')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10212')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10213')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10242')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10249')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10256')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10257')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10258')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10259')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10260')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10261')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10265')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10268')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10269')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10270')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10271')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10272')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10273')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10274')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10275')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10276')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10277')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10278')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10279')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10280')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10281')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10282')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10285')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10286')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10292')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10301')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10302')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10303')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10304')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10305')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10306')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10307')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10308')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10309')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10310')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10311')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10312')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10313')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10314')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10451')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10452')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10453')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10454')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10455')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10456')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10457')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10458')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10459')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10460')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10461')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10462')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10463')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10464')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10465')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10466')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10467')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10468')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10469')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10470')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10471')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10472')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10473')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10474')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10475')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10499')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10501')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10502')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10503')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10504')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10505')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10506')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10507')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10509')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10510')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10511')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10512')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10514')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10516')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10517')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10518')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10519')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10520')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10521')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10522')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10523')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10524')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10526')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10527')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10528')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10530')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10532')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10533')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10535')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10536')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10537')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10538')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10540')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10541')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10542')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10543')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10545')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10546')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10547')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10548')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10549')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10550')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10551')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10552')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10553')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10557')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10558')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10560')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10562')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10566')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10567')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10570')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10571')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10572')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10573')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10576')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10577')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10578')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10579')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10580')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10583')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10587')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10588')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10589')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10590')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10591')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10594')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10595')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10596')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10597')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10598')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10601')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10602')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10603')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10604')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10605')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10606')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10607')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10610')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10701')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10702')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10703')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10704')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10705')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10706')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10707')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10708')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10709')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10710')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10801')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10802')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10803')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10804')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10805')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10901')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10910')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10911')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10912')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10913')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10914')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10915')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10916')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10917')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10918')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10919')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10920')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10921')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10922')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10923')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10924')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10925')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10926')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10927')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10928')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10930')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10931')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10932')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10933')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10940')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10941')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10943')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10949')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10950')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10952')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10953')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10954')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10956')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10958')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10959')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10960')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10962')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10963')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10964')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10965')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10968')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10969')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10970')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10973')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10974')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10975')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10976')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10977')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10979')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10980')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10981')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10982')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10983')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10984')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10985')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10986')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10987')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10988')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10989')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10990')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10992')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10993')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10994')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10996')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10997')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('10998')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11001')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11002')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11003')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11004')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11005')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11010')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11020')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11021')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11022')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11023')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11024')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11025')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11026')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11027')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11030')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11040')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11041')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11042')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11043')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11044')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11050')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11051')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11052')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11053')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11054')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11055')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11096')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11099')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11101')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11102')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11103')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11104')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11105')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11106')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11109')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11120')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11201')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11202')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11203')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11204')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11205')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11206')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11207')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11208')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11209')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11210')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11211')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11212')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11213')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11214')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11215')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11216')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11217')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11218')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11219')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11220')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11221')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11222')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11223')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11224')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11225')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11226')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11228')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11229')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11230')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11231')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11232')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11233')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11234')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11235')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11236')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11237')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11238')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11239')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11240')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11241')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11242')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11243')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11244')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11245')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11247')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11248')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11249')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11251')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11252')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11254')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11255')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11256')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11351')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11352')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11354')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11355')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11356')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11357')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11358')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11359')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11360')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11361')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11362')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11363')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11364')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11365')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11366')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11367')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11368')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11369')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11370')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11371')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11372')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11373')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11374')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11375')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11377')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11378')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11379')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11380')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11381')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11385')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11386')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11390')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11405')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11411')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11412')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11413')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11414')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11415')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11416')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11417')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11418')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11419')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11420')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11421')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11422')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11423')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11424')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11425')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11426')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11427')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11428')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11429')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11430')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11431')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11432')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11433')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11434')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11435')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11436')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11439')
INSERT INTO Table_ZipCode(ZipCode)  Values ('11451')
```